# Finding and matching a specific character between two characters in RegEx

Tags: php, regex

Sorry because I'm new to RegEx. I want to find **all the hyphens inside the parentheses** in this string:

```
$router->get('template-123s', 'Template123Controller@index')->name('template-123s');

$router->get('template-123s/{id}', 'Template123Controller@show')->name('get-template-123');
```

The hyphens outside the parenthesis ***must not be matched*** (for example, the first occurrence of the hyphen (`..ter->get..`) in the string and I'm having a hard time solving this problem.

[Here is one of my attempts in trying to find the hyphens between the parenthesis, which is currently not working.](https://regexr.com/3k30k)

[Here is a sample attempt of matching all the characters between the hyphens and it works.](https://regexr.com/3k310)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work **for the example strings which you have provided**:

```
-(?=[^()]*\))
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mmA9GC/1)

**Explanation:**

- `-` - matches `-`
- `(?=[^()]*\))` - positive lookahead to make sure that the `-` matched in the above step must be followed by a closing `)` without encountering either a `(` or a `)` before that.

**NOTE**: This would not work properly if you have nested parenthesis.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting it as the answer IF IT SATISFIES ALL YOUR TEST STRINGS

Comment: StackOverflow says I must wait one minute to accept an answer! >_<

Answer (score 0):

`r'\(.*?(-).*?\)'`
assuming regex in php is the same as in python.  Note that outside parentheses are escaped with a \, and the insides signify a group

Comment: Sorry dude, cannot work even in Python flavor, thanks nonetheless! https://regex101.com/r/35DGxs/1

Comment: appologies, I forgot to add the raw string designation at the beginning